# How to solve dimnames error for matrix in R

Tags: r

I am using this code to make a matrix:

```
input1 <- read_excel("input.xlsx")
MAT <- as.matrix(input1[,2:400])
Height <- MAT[1,]
Expres <- MAT[2:36000,]
row.names(Expres) <- input1[2:36000, 1]
```

My input data has `400 samples` with `36000 genes` and `Height` in row 2 and the data subset looks like:

```
Gene Sample1 Sample2 -- Sample400
Height 5 10 -- 7 
Gene1 0.5 0.6 -- 0.9
Gene2 0.4 0.7 -- 0.3
Gene36000 0.5 0.6 -- 0.1
```

but I am getting an error for the last line:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `readxl::read_excel`, it's returning a `tibble`, and `[` indexing is not doing what you expect.

Your expectation works with a `data.frame`:

```r
mtcars[2:3,1]
# [1] 21.0 22.8
```

but not with a `tibble`:

```r
as_tibble(mtcars)[2:3,1]
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1  21  
# 2  22.8

as_tibble(mtcars)[[1]][2:3]
# [1] 21.0 22.8
```

Instead, use

```r
row.names(Expres) <- input1[[1]][2:36000]
```

---

Incidentally, the expected behavior can be forced in both directions

```r
mtcars[2:3, 1, drop = FALSE]
#                mpg
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0
# Datsun 710    22.8
as_tibble(mtcars)[2:3, 1, drop = TRUE]
# [1] 21.0 22.8
```

Sadly, the use of `drop=` works with `data.frame` and `tbl_df`, but not with the third `data.frame` variant `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[2:3, 1, drop = TRUE]
#     mpg
# 1: 21.0
# 2: 22.8
as.data.table(mtcars)[2:3, 1, drop = FALSE]
#     mpg
# 1: 21.0
# 2: 22.8
as.data.table(mtcars)[[1]][2:3]
# [1] 21.0 22.8
```

(A source of many hours of trouble-shooting for me some time ago.)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I also want to drop the rows with all zero values and I am using SUMS <- rowSums(Expres) 
Expres <- Expres[SUMS > 0,] but it shows an error Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: That error suggests that there is at least one column in `Expres` that is not one of `logical`, `integer`, or `numeric`. This includes `factor`, `character`, `Date`, and `POSIXt` (to name a few). Look at `str(Expres)` and look for rows that don't have `"lgl"`, `"int"`, `"num"` as their abbreviated class.